# What's the best way to DRY Java code ? Creating private method with different Objects for parameters?

Tags: java, dry, code-cleanup

I'm creating a RTS game and one of the features is to construct differend kind of buildings. I'm finding a lot of repetition and I was thinking to extract it in helper method, but the problem is that every building is different object which inharits some propertyes from the main building class.

The building methods looks like this:

```
  public static void buildDockyard(Base base) {
    if (Validator.checkForBuilding(base, "Dockyard")) {
       throw new IllegalStateException("Dockyard is already build");
     }
    Dockyard dockyard = new Dockyard("Dockyard");
    int requiredPower = dockyard.requiredResource("power");
    int requiredStardust = dockyard.requiredResource("stardust");
    int requiredPopulation = dockyard.requiredResource("population");

    Validator.checkResource(base, requiredPower, requiredStardust, requiredPopulation);
    updateResourceAfterBuild(base, requiredPower, requiredStardust, requiredPopulation);
    dockyard.setCompleteTime(dockyard.requiredResource("time"));
    base.getBuildings().add(dockyard);
  }

  public static void buildHotel(Base base) {
    if (Validator.checkForBuilding(base, "Space Hotel")) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Space Hotel is already build");
    }

    SpaceHotel spaceHotel = new SpaceHotel("Space Hotel");
    int requiredPower = spaceHotel.requiredResource("power");
    int requiredStardust = spaceHotel.requiredResource("stardust");
    int requiredPopulation = spaceHotel.requiredResource("population");

    Validator.checkResource(base, requiredPower, requiredStardust, requiredPopulation);
    updateResourceAfterBuild(base, requiredPower, requiredStardust, requiredPopulation);
    spaceHotel.setCompleteTime(spaceHotel.requiredResource("time"));
    base.getBuildings().add(spaceHotel);

    base.setCapacity(base.getCapacity() + spaceHotel.getCapacity());
  }
```

I was thinking to refactor like this:
The helper method

```
private static void construct(Building building, Base base) {
    int requiredPower = building.requiredResource("power");
    int requiredStardust = building.requiredResource("stardust");
    int requiredPopulation = building.requiredResource("population");

    Validator.checkResource(base, requiredPower, requiredStardust, requiredPopulation);
    updateResourceAfterBuild(base, requiredPower, requiredStardust, requiredPopulation);
    building.setCompleteTime(building.requiredResource("time"));
  }
```

Aimed result

```
public static void buildDockyard(Base base) {
        if (Validator.checkForBuilding(base, "Dockyard")) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("Dockyard is already build");
         }
        Dockyard dockyard = new Dockyard("Dockyard");
        construct(dockyar, base);
        base.getBuildings().add(dockyard);
      }
```

The problem is that each building has unique properties and resource requirements and the main Building class doesn't know about them, so I can't use it as a parameter in the helper method.

All of this is happening in a static helper class for the Base class.

How would you refactor this code ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: To give you a starting point: Why do you need extract the required resources to pass them separately to the validator? Wouldn't it be easier when a validator can handle a building directly? And when the validator only checks if the required resources are available in `base`, then why would the validator check that itself? Can't request the given building to tell if the available resources are enough for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to DRY in Java when making games is to have a clear understanding and terminology of your game. If you read any **modern** board game manual you will soon see that they will use exactly one word for one concept, like `Turn`, `Round`, `Building`, `Player`, `Resource`. This allows to form a rough structure: A `Building` costs a certain amount of `Resource`. If a player hasn't enough of `Resource` then tell him "We need more vespine gas.", etc. The clearer the picture, the DRY-er your Java and easier to create the necessary Classes for your code.

**Parameters**

If you end up with something like this:

```
public static void someFunction(Base base, Object param1, Object param2)
public static void someOtherFunc(Base base, Object paramA, Object paramB)
...
```

Then this is a strong hint that maybe both functions should be part of the `Base` class.

**Enums**

If you have a limited set of values then Java Enums can be fantastic to represent them, e.g. your Resource system:

```
public enum Resource {
    POWER, STARDUST, POPULATION
}
```

Now you don't have to remember if you called it "stardust", "Stardust" or if you even still have a Resource like "stardust". Instead you can use `int requiredPower = building.requiredResource(Resource.POWER);`

**Polymorphism**

Let's suppose we have two classes, `Building` and `StarHotel`, with `StarHotel` being a specific kind of `Building`. Having an abstract class `Building` allows us to handle some general mechanics in a specific manner, like this:

```
public abstract class Building {
    private ... cost;
    private ... requirements;
    private ... 

    // Std-Getter and Setter methods
    public ... getCost() { return this.cost; }

}
```

EVERY Building has a cost, and requirements and other important variables. BUT we handled all the standard stuff of getting and setting these generic variables to a base class from which we now can extend other, more specific buildings. Thanks to the `extends` keyword you can get the Cost of a `StarHotel` Object without filling the `StarHotel` class with repetitive Getters and Setters.

```
public class StarHotel extends Building {
    // Getter, Setter inherited from Building class
}
```

**Interfaces**

Java Interfaces allow you to define Interfaces which define methods. In laymen terms: This is useful, because every Class that implements an Interface must implement the method, unless the interface provides the `default` implementation.

```
public interface ResourceProvider {
    void provideResourceFor(Base base); // A Resource Provider provides Resource for a base.
}
```

With this interface we have defined that if some Class implements `ResourceProvider` it has to specify how and what resources to provide for some `Base` object. Our interface does not care which Resource, which Base and even what `provideResourceFor` could mean, but as long as something implements `ResourceProvider` it has to provide the functionality.

**Putting all together**

Putting Enums, Interface and Polymorphism together, we can now create a `StarHotel` class that extends `Building` and implements `ResourceProvider`, providing 8 Food units and 2 Happiness units to our Base.

```
public class StarHotel extends Building implements ResourceProvider
    public void provideResourceFor(Base base) {
        base.addResource(Resource.FOOD, 8);
        base.addResource(Resource.HAPPINESS, 2);
    }
}
```

That might be much to take in, but hopefully it will give you a good direction where to look further.

Answer (score 5):

Your problems start with using static methods for everything. In an object oriented world you ideally have an object `Base` and it would have a non-static method `addStructure(Struture structure)` were `Structure` is an interface for example. Now you would have objects like `Building` and `Dockyard` which would implement `Structure`.

Implentation of `addStructure` would be something like this:

```
if (getBuildings().contains(structure)) {
   throw new IllegalStateException(structure.name + " is already build");
}
if (validateStillHaveEnoughResourcesFor(structure)) {
   throw new IllegalStateException(structure.name + " can not be added. Not enough resources");
}
getBuildings().add(structure);
```

Validating structure itself should not be in base. Validating how structure fits to the base should be in the base.

Comment: Thank you ! 
I forgot to mention that all of this is happening in a helper class for the Base class that's whjy all the methods are static same with the Validator (a lot of validations is going on :D )

Comment: @Ili that is not a good reason for making methods static. Not saying that they don't need to be necessarily, but the reason given is not, in itself, a good reason to make that kind of design decision. The point Tarmo makes is not only valid, it might be directly related to your problem. You should consider reexamining your decision and perhaps follow his advice, ESPECIALLY, if these "helper" classes are being used to store data.